# Ember model relationship navigation in a controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need to navigate through my relationships inside a controller and have not figured out how to do it. I have the following models.

```js
// models/asset.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.belongsTo('lookup', {inverse: null, async: true}),
  children: DS.hasMany('asset', {inverse: 'parent', async: true}),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('asset', {inverse: 'children', async: true})
});
```

```js
// models/lookup.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('string'),
  children: DS.hasMany('lookup', {inverse: 'parent', async: true}),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('lookup', {inverse: 'children', async: true})
});
```

The type of my current asset is based on the child records of the parent asset.
In an action in the controller I need to get the current asset's parent's type's children. I would *like* to just use:

```js
return this.store.findAll('lookup', this.get('asset.parent.type.children')).then(function(parentTypeChildren) {});
```

But life is not so easy.

If I have the asset loaded and I do `this.get('asset.parent')` do I get the full asset record or just the parent asset ID?

Any hints about this? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `async: true`, a `this.get('asset.parent')` would trigger a server call (if it is not already in the store) and fetch the parent asset (as a `set` call) and return it as a promise. `this.get('asset.data.parent')` would return the id of the parent.

So basically you should try something like this (under the assumption that the `asset.parent.type` is already in your store):

```
var childrenLookUps = this.get('asset.parent.type.children');
childrenLookUps.then(function(){
    // do something with your childrenLookUps
});
```

Comment: Thanks Remi, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: My issue was understanding and working with promises. Just because a function returns a promise does not mean that it has retrieved the records yet. Promises that you are unsure about should be managed with a `then(function(){});`. Only then can you be sure the promise has been fulfilled. Thanks for your help @Remi.